# Python: do r = random_stuff() while not meets_condition(r)

Tags: python, design-patterns, do-while

I often have to randomly generate stuff with certain constraints. In many cases, it's quicker to ignore the constraints in generation, check if they are met afterwards and redo the process otherwise. Lacking a `do` keyword, I usually write

```
r = random_stuff()
while not meets_condition(r):
    r = random_stuff()
```

That's a bit ugly, as I have the same line of code twice. What I'd really like to have is a construct like

```
r = random_stuff() until meets_condition(r)
```

similar to the ternary operator introduced in 2.5:

```
a = b if condition else c
```

Just that here condition is evaluated before the left-hand side of the statement is executed. Does anybody have a suggestion for a design pattern (should work in Python 2.7) that remedies the `while`-constructs intrinsic unpythonic ugliness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe syntactic sugar is what the Dr. ordered?  You could do something like this.

I was too lazy to handle kw args in find_condition.  You get what you pay for :D.

```
def find_condition(cond_mk, cond_ck, *args):
    """
    .. function:: find_condition(cond_mk, cond_ck) -> cond

       Create conditions by calling cond_mk until one is found that passes
       the condition check, cond_ck.  Once cond_ck returns True, iteration 
       over cond_mk stops and the last value processed is returned.

       ** WARNING **
       This function could loop infinitely.

       ``cond_mk`` - callable that creates a condition.  It's return value is
       passed to cond_ck for verification.

       ``cond_ck`` - callable that checks the return value of cond_mk.  

       ``args`` - any arguments to pass to cond_mk should be supplied here.
    """
    v = cond_mk(*args)
    while not cond_ck(v):
        v = cond_mk(*args)
    return v

# Test it out..
import random
random.seed()
print find_condition(random.randint, lambda x: x > 95, 1, 100)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
while True:
    r = random_stuff()
    if meets_condition(r):
        break
```

or

```
condition = True
while condition:
    r = random_stuff()
    condition = not meets_condition(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is not bad - but not with the new keyword `until`, but rather like

```
a = (<expression> while <condition>)
```

extending the idea of [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

As they don't exist, it won't help you.

---

But what you can use, is the [`iter` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#iter) with the sentinel.

```
dummy_sentinel = object()
for r in iter(random_stuff, dummy_sentinel):
    if meets_condition(r): break
```

If you can be sure about your `random_stuff()` returning only a certain kind of values, such as numbers, strings, etc., you can take some other value as sentinel. Especially, when `None` never can occur, take this, in order to have a never-ending generator.

```
for r in iter(random_stuff, None):
    if meets_condition(r): break
```

Then `random_stuff()` gets called until it meets the condition.

---

Even better might be

```
r = next(r for r in iter(random_stuff, None) if meets_condition(r))
```

which gives you the first matching one.

Comment: gotta give +1 for fresh approach even this isn't the pythonic way

Comment: You can use `object()` as athe perfect seninel.

Answer (score 0):

```
while not meets_condition(random_stuff()): pass
```

If you actually need the `random_stuff()` then it can be stored elsewhere as a side effect (e.g. make `random_stuff` the `__call__` method of a class).

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't give me the result of `random_stuff()`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, inspired by @jaime I wrote the following decorator:

```
def retry(condition):
    def deco_retry(f):
        def f_retry(*args, **kwargs):
            success = False
            while not success:
                result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                success = condition(result)
            return result
        return f_retry
    return deco_retry
```

Now, the following works:

```
def condition(calue):    
    return value < .5

@retry(condition)
def random_stuff():
    return random.random()

print random_stuff()
```

Also, inline:

```
@retry(lambda x: x < .5)
def random_stuff():
    return random.random()

print random_stuff()
```

However, the retry is now bound to the `random_stuff()` method, which can now only be used with the condition with which it was decorated. Also, it doesn't work for instance methods (as in `@retry(self.condition)`). Any ideas to circumvent that?